# Pandas merge multiple data frames and create pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-science, pivot-table

How can I build a pandas pivot table using data from two different dataframes?

**Table 1:**
[Data frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKeJy.png)

```
A    B       C    D
1   apple   100 qwerty
2   apple   101 qwerty1
3   apple   102 qwerty2
```

**Table 2:**

[Data frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcJAn.png)

```
A     B      C    D
1   orange  200 asdfgh1
2   orange  201 asdfgh2
3   orange  202 asdfgh3
```

Pivot table goal:

[Goal Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcMmJ.png)

```
                    C         D
A         B
1       apple      100      qwerty
        orange     200      asdfgh1
2       apple      101      qwerty1
        orange     201      asdfgh2
```

Comment: `df1.append(df2)` ?

Comment: that works thanks

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': ['apple']*3 , 'C': [100, 101, 102], 'D': ['qwerty', 'qwerty1', 'qwerty2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': ['orange']*3 , 'C': [200, 201, 202], 'D': ['asdfgh', 'asdfgh1', 'asdfgh2']})

pd.concat((df,df2)).groupby(['A', 'B']).first()

            C        D
A B
1 apple   100   qwerty
  orange  200   asdfgh
2 apple   101  qwerty1
  orange  201  asdfgh1
3 apple   102  qwerty2
  orange  202  asdfgh2
```